# array.prototype.map() Need to Calculate Won, Lost, Tied for NFL Team

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I am experimenting with the .map() array method and cannot find the correct syntax to generate the “wlt” column in my object. “wlt” stands for Win, Loss, or Tie.

Currently I am generating the “wlt” column with the following code:

```
    const scores = philadephiaEaglesScores.map(function(item){
    const obj = {
    "weekNumber": item.weekNumber, 
    "name": item.ourName, 
    "oppName": item.oppName, 
    "ourScore": item.ourScore,
    "oppScore":  item.oppScore,
    "wlt": item.ourScore - item.oppScore
    }
    return obj;
    });
```

This does work and gives me a positive number if we won the game, a negative number is we lost the game and 0 if the game was a tie.

I would like to take it to the next level and actually generate a string value of Won, Lost, or Tie in the first code example.

I can get that to work using the following code, but cannot get the second code example to work inside the first code example.

```
    let winLossTie = philadephiaEaglesScores.map(item => {
    if (item.ourScore > item.oppScore) {
    return "W";
    } if (item.ourScore < item.oppScore) {
    return "L";
    } else {return "T"}
    });
```

```
My JSON data is listed below:
    const philadephiaEaglesScores = [
    {"weekNumber": "1","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Redskins", "ourScore": "32", 
    "oppScore": "27", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "2","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Falcons", "ourScore": "20", 
    "oppScore": "27", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "3","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Lions", "ourScore": "24", "oppScore": 
    "27", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "4","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Packers", "ourScore": "34", 
    "oppScore": "27", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "5","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Packers", "ourScore": "31", 
    "oppScore": "6", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "6","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Vikings", "ourScore": "20", 
    "oppScore": "38", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "7","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Cowboys", "ourScore": "10", 
    "oppScore": "37", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "8","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Bills", "ourScore": "31", "oppScore": 
    "13", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "9","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Bears", "ourScore": "22", "oppScore": 
    "14", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "11","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Patriots", "ourScore": "10", 
    "oppScore": "17", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "12","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Seahawks", "ourScore": "9", 
    "oppScore": "17", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "13","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Dolphins", "ourScore": "31", 
    "oppScore": "37", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "14","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Giants", "ourScore": "23", 
    "oppScore": "17", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "15","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Redskins", "ourScore": "37", 
    "oppScore": "27", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "16","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Cowboys", "ourScore": "17", 
    "oppScore": "9", "location": ""},
    {"weekNumber": "17","ourName": "Philadephia Eagles", "oppName": "Giants", "ourScore": "37", 
    "oppScore": "17", "location": ""},
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator replace for if/else statement.

It'll look like this:

```
    const scores = philadephiaEaglesScores.map(function(item){
    const obj = {
    "weekNumber": item.weekNumber, 
    "name": item.ourName, 
    "oppName": item.oppName, 
    "ourScore": item.ourScore,
    "oppScore":  item.oppScore,
    "wlt": item.ourScore > item.oppScore ? "W" : item.ourScore < item.oppScore ? "L" : "T"
    }
    return obj;
    });
```

You may want to separate ternary to a statement/expression/function for more clean code.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, change:

```
"wlt": item.ourScore - item.oppScore
```

to:

```
"wlt": "LTW"[1+Math.sign(item.ourScore - item.oppScore)]
```

You cannot actually use the second function where you iterate the *whole* array. It would work if that function would take as argument *one* object from the array, and would just return the string applicable for that object only. Then you could call that function like so:

```
"wlt": winLossTie(item)
```

So, to be clear, the function would need to change to the following:

```
function winLossTie(item) {
  if (item.ourScore > item.oppScore) {
    return "W";
  } if (item.ourScore < item.oppScore) {
    return "L";
  } else {
    return "T"
  }
});
```

But the shortcut, using `Math.sign` (which returns -1, 0 or 1), makes it short enough to not need a separate function at all.